# autocapital words not working in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code to make the first letter bold:

```
  self.firstNameTexField_.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    self.lastNameTextField_.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    self.emailTextField_.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

However, this doesn't make the first letter of the word capital. Any idea why?

Comment: If you type in the text field using your keyboard, it will ignore auto capitalization. However if you use the keypad on the simulator screen, it will auto-capitalize it.

Comment: I am testing this on my device

Comment: Can you put up all your textField http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html As per this you need to specify all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.firstNameTexField_.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

Change

```
self.firstNameTexField_.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
```

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer. This change will simply make the text field all caps.

Comment: See Richard's answer

Comment: What kind of answer is this ?

Answer (score 29):

Not mentioned here is that some keyboard types don't support the auto-cap feature, most notably:

> `NamePhonePad` Specifies a keypad designed for entering a person’s
>   name or phone number. This keyboard type does not support
>   auto-capitalization.

Why a keyboard designed for a person's name doesn't support autocap is beyond me.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@UIKeyboardType

Comment: Very bad design

Comment: thanks for this - the fact that this combo of settings didn't work drove me a tiny bit insane for about 30 mins! lol... Crazy that Name Phone Pad doesn't support the word cap!

Comment: Even It was not working if keyboard type set default. I checked this in device as well.
My problem was - Autocapitalization was turned off on device Settings->General->Keyboard

Comment: In answer to "Why a keyboard designed for a person's name doesn't support autocap?" : Neil deGrasse Tyson

Answer (score 14):

Are you testing this in the simulator while typing on your computer's keyboard? When you do this the auto capitalization doesn't apply. If you tap on the keyboard in the app you should see the desired effect.

Comment: Have you verified (using the debugger and a breakpoint) that at the time you attempt to set the autocapitalization property for these text fields, that the text field references are not nil?

Comment: yes it is no nil, as it is from the nib.. I've also set it up in the nib file such that it autocapitalize the words

Comment: Great clarification point...I was running into the same issue and thought it was my code, but in fact I was simply typing on my keyboard instead of the virtual keyboard in simulator. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was I was calling `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` before setting the `autocapitalizationType`. Once I switched the order so that `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` came **after** setting `autocapitalizationType`, it worked as expected.